# AWS EC2 + Asterisk + My landline/Mobile number

Tags: amazon-ec2, asterisk, pbx

I have some vague idea about how to play around with Asterisk. Once we installed Asterisk on a server running Linux in our company premises. On the same box we installed a Digium card - which we connected to the PBX box(installed by our telco) in our premises. After this configuration  - we were able to take incoming calls on our landline number  - as well as make outgoing calls originating from the same number.

Now, I have read that it's possible to install Asterisk on EC2. But then how do I connect it to my landline number - so that I can take incoming calls as well as make outgoing calls from the same number?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of card you need ATA device sip2e1 or sip2fxo depend of you current cards.

So you can use that device as sip trunk and not need put anything into your ec2 instance(that is not posible)

Also you can use your current asterisk as sip2pstn device. Read any asterisk book, it have examples of asterisk interconnection.